# Clearing up output in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to set up visual studio code so that when I run my python code, it is only showing the code output. Currently, the terminal shows the filepath and powershell information. I just want to see the code output so the terminal looks less crowded. Any suggestions?

I'm not sure if I have to go into settings or download an extension. I am not very familiar with visual studio code.

```
print('Hello, World.')
```

Current Output:
`PS C:\Users\william.jessup\Documents\Exercise Files> &` `C:/Users/william.jessup/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe`

```
"c:/Users/william.jessup/Documents/Exercise Files/Chap01/hello-working.py"
Hello, World.

PS C:\Users\william.jessup\Documents\Linkedn\PythonEssentials\Exercise Files>
```

I just want to see:
Hello, World.

Comment: First check your python path is set in environment variable or not by simply typing python on command line.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to hide that information via the Python extension as it is executing the code via the terminal and so it's a side-effect of how the execution works. We also can't avoid using the terminal because if you call something like `input()` which requires a terminal to type something in live then printing only to the Output Panel would break your code.